# Regex .htaccess block requests where the uri starts with a period or underscore

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use the .htaccess file to block what appear to be malicious requests to my project. I have some `RewriteCond` to block by User Agent but I now want to take care of requests that contain a path that begins with `.` or `_`.

As an example, I want to block these: 
`https://my.project.url/.web`
`https://my.project.url/_backup`

But I want to allow these:
`https://my/api/version/current_product`
`https://my.project.url/something.php`

I have some expressions that block requests to common endpoints:
`RewriteRule ^.*wp-admin - [NC,F]`
but don't know how to start to modifying that to block the new spam requests.

Comment: `^.*wp-admin` is `anything until wp-admin`. Is `/` your base, if so `^[.-]` should be if it starts with a `.` or `-`.

Comment: That is the issue, the base is not static. Ideally I would like both `my.project.url/_backup` AND `my.project.url/valid_uri/_invalid_here` to be blocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule .*/[\._].* - [F]
```

That's a bit easier to read. The NC is not needed since neither . or _ have a case, and everything else is a wildcard.

Comment: You don't need to escape the `.` in a character class. http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html

Comment: Because I do so much shell stuff, I try to avoid different methods, ie, I try to follow one rule for everything if I can, ie, escape . always, in gawk, sed, bash, apache regex, php regex, etc. But it is good to point out that it's not needed in this case, though years of gawk/bash have taught me to always be specific, if only for readability's sake..

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with, and it works for my use case:
`RewriteRule (.*\/\.|.*\/_) - [NC,F]`

To translate:
If there is any part of the path containing `/.` or `/_` then the request is forbidden.